# Casperjs unable to perform the demo

Tags: casperjs

my casperjs can't execute the example.js ,

phantomjs 2.1.1
capserjs  1.1.3

example.js

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

when i execute casperjs example.js , it show me this;

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process
phantomjs://platform/path.js:26
```

Comment: How did you install PhantomJS and CasperJS? How are you executing it?

Comment: I solve this problem , I reinstall